# laravel pivot table id as foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image]

A company_user can have many user groups. so how can i associate many user group to the same user based on their companies. example: a user associated with one  company can have usergroup of both admin and user. how to create table and relationship for to achieve this.

Comment: you should read up on laravel relations https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships